# "any" or "each" for "We also expect ___ place to be appropriate to its use."

Tags: word-usage

The context is as follows

The importance of interior design becomes evident when we realize how much time we spend surrounded by four walls. Whenever we need to be indoors, we want our surroundings to be as attractive and comfortable as possible. We also expect ___ place to be appropriate to its use. You would be shocked if the inside of your bedroom were suddenly changed to look like the inside of a restaurant.

Thanks

To me, "each" implies a range (which is missing here in the context) while "any" refers to a generic thing. But I'm not sure.

Comment: How does "each" imply a range?

Comment: [From Longman Dictionary of Contemporary English] every one of two or more things or people, considered separately - hence the "range". What confuses me is, can each be used at the very first mention of something new in the context, without implied "range" of such?

Comment: Perhaps you're confused about "range". A range is a continuous span of values from one point to another, like the numbers: 2, 3, 4, 5 are a range from 2 to 8. There is no "range" implied here. The rooms of a building don't follow a sequence. They're an unordered set.

Comment: Thank you very much @gotube . I realize I meant "a group of similar things" by "range".  Could you please shed some light on the original question, too? Can "any" and "each" both be put in the blank to complete the sentence? Much appreciated!

Comment: I'll be happy to answer the question if you edit it to make sense by removing "range". I'm not going to provide an answer to a question that isn't there. The answer must make sense to anyone reading *just the question*, and not the comments here